# How can i encrypt and sign iphone configuration files using openssl command?

Tags: ios, encryption, openssl

I have created configuration profile using iPhone Configuration Utility. I want to sign and encrypt configuration profiles using my own ssl certificate.

I could successfully sign configuration profiles using the below command

openssl smime -sign -in test_config.mobileconfig -out signed_test_config.mobileconfig -signer signing.crt -inkey signing.key -certfile CA.crt -inform der -outform der -nodetach

But i don't know how to encrypt the profile using openssl command. Do i need to add any extra parameters in the above command to encrypt iphone configuration profile?